# automorphism group of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$, I would like to calculate $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. From definition of $\operatorname{Aut}()$ we know:

- $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\le \operatorname{Sym}(G) $

If the group is finitely generated and abelian I should use those properties:

- $\operatorname{Aut}(G \times H) \cong\operatorname{Aut}(G) \times\operatorname{Aut}(H)  $
- $\operatorname{Aut}( C_n) \cong \Phi(C_n)$
- $\operatorname{Aut}({\bf Z})\cong C_2$

Where $G,H$ are(not necessarily abelian) groups of coprime order and $C_n$ is cyclic of order n.

In case the group is not abelian, if the group $G$ is complete, then:

- $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=G$

In case of other groups (ex. semi-direct products) how should I proceed?

Edit:

I just want to know if there are other criterions for such calculations. For example: if I have a semi-direct product, what can I do?

Comment: What is a complete group? Also, what are you actually asking about, exactly?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a totally general way to compute automorphism groups.  You might be interested in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO(8)#Spin.288.29

Comment: Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group

Comment: Complete means centerless (i.e. Z(G)={0})

Comment: Aut(G x H) is not isomorphic to Aut(G) x Aut(H). Perhaps you want the orders of G,H to be coprime.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, you're right. I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 2):

There is no one general way to find automorphism groups. For direct products there are papers of Bidwell et al. that give the answer in terms of the factors. The argument there is in the family of Krull-Schmidt arguments. The original arguments can be simplified and streamlined a bit, but the answer is fairly simple and intuitive.

For semidirect products there is work of McCurran and others. The description is similar to the direct product case, except this time you need things to respect the action.

In either case you still need a way to describe $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ when $G$ is indecomposable, for which there is no one single method. Automorphisms and central automorphisms of $p$-groups are still not a completely solved problem, for example.

Google searches easily bring up a wealth of papers on such topics.